# Combined Markov Chain of N identical Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains, discrete-time

I have a markov chain from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9766097 as follows

[image]

The state transition matrix is as below

[image]

The analysis pertains to packet drop rate for **ONE** device with certain arrival($\lambda$) and transmission success probability($\mu_1$) where $\bar\lambda$ stands for no arrivals ($1-\lambda$) and $\bar\mu_1$ pertains to transmission failure probability ($1-\mu_1$).

The drop rate for ONE device is given by $\pi_d\bar\mu_1$ where $\pi_d$ is the steady state probability for the markov chain with delay bound $d$ (after which a packet will be dropped) in state $d$

I need to calculate the ***combined drop rate*** for **N** devices which are identical and symmetrical (i.e. have the same probability for successful transmission). What is the correct approach to extend this analysis for **N** devices?  May be it is trivial, but I am missing the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean *expected* drop rate (since actual drop rate is stochastic).

Let $D_i$ be the drop rate of device $i$. You are asking about the following quantity:

$$E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N D_i \right]$$

Where we are assuming the $D_i$ are iid.

You pointed out that $E[D_i] = \pi_d\bar \mu_1$ therefore, by linearity of expectation, we should expect $N\pi_d\bar \mu_1$ combined drop rate.

The steady state distribution of combined drop rate would be the discrete convolution of $N$ copies of $\pi_d$

Comment: minor input, $\pi_d\bar \mu_1$  is the drop probability derived from Markov analysis. Is it ok to understand it as an expected value?

Comment: @YuktiKaura -- I interpreted it as an average drop rate because $\pi_d$ is a steady-state probability (over many packets) for one device. Over a large number of packets we find the device spends $\pi_d$ percent of its time in the final state, and of the times its in the final state, it will fail again $\bar \mu_1$ percent of the time, so the packet will be dropped. So, if I have several devices, each getting the same packet rate and having same behavior, then each on, on average will also drop at rate $\pi_d \bar \mu_1$

Comment: Thank you... Got it, but when we multiply the expected value with $N$ the drop rate may no longer stay within the range [0,1]

Comment: @YuktiKaura since it's a rate I wasn't expecting that to be an issue -- if you have 1000 devices they will drop $1000\pi_d\bar \mu_1$ packets per unit time.

Or...are you asking for the probability that ANY of the devices will drop something (like in reliability engineering) in which case it would be something like $1-(\pi_d\mu_1)^N$

Comment: Precisely, the formulation $N\pi_d\mu_1$ would give us the expected number of packets dropped across total $N$ devices. Drop rate would then be  the ratio of number of packets dropped (from the formulation above) to the number of packets transmitted ain't it?

Comment: @YuktiKaura I think it boils down to what rate you are looking for: dropped packets per unit X --> what is X? My answer assumes we are looking at the total number of packets dropped across all $N$ per unit time (i.e., the time unit used to calculate $\lambda, \mu$.).

Comment: @YuktiKaura However, there other drop rates but we need to assume something about the relationship among the packets received by each device. 

If each device receives a copy of the same packet (i.e., redundant transmission) then as long as at least one devices sends successfully, the message will be transmitted (I know I'm simplifying here -- not a network engineer :) 

In this case, we are no longer talking about a rate but a packet drop probability for the system of N devices , which would be $(1-\pi_d\bar \mu_1)^N \xrightarrow{N \to \infty} 0$

Comment: @YuktiKaura Finally -- if you are looking for dropped packets as a fraction of total packets received, as we assume they are completely independent (no redundancy) then this fraction will the same as for a single device.\

Comment: Thank you Annika for detailing to such length.